# Wrap a heavy non-React component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a large, heavy non-React component `HeavyThing`. Now I'd like to wrap this component as a React component to use it inside a React app.

Two questions regarding this:

1. Is it correct to store the `heavyThing` in a state? I fear that when something inside `heavyThing` changes, the component will get re-rendered by react all the time.
2. Data is passed into the React component using `props.data`, but the `HeavyThing` only knows `clearData` and `addData` to set new data. I fear that `useEffect` to set new data would clear and add the data many many times even if there's no new data. Do I need to implement some mechanism that checks whether `props.data` has changed? How?

Maybe I'm doing it completely wrong, so I'm very open to better patterns.

```
export default function HeavyComponentWrapper(props) {
    const elementRef = useRef();

    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);
    const [heavyThing, setHeavyThing] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        if(!initialized){
            const h = new HeavyThing();
            await h.when();
            setHeavyThing(h); // Ok to store the reference in a state?
            setInitialized(true);
        }
        heavyThing.clearData(); // Right way to ....
        heavyThing.addData(props.data); // ... update data?
    });

    return (
        <div className="targetDiv" ref={elementRef}>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Is  HeavyThing a Singleton store then [useSyncExternalStore](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usesyncexternalstore) may work

Answer (score 1):

```
export default function HeavyComponentWrapper(props) {
    const heavyComponentRef = useRef(new HeavyThing());

    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        h.when().then(() => setInitialized(true));
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        heavyThing.clearData();
        heavyThing.addData(props.data);
    }, [props.data]);


    return (
        <div />
    );
}
```

or if you need to mount it in the div

```
export default function HeavyComponentWrapper(props) {
    const wrapperElementRef = useRef(null);
    const heavyComponentRef = useRef();

    const [initialized, setInitialized] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        heavyComponentRef.current = new HeavyThing({container: wrapperElementRef.current})
        h.when().then(() => setInitialized(true));
    }, []);


    useEffect(() => {
        heavyThing.clearData();
        heavyThing.addData(props.data);
    }, [props.data]);


    return (
        <div ref={wrapperElementRef} />
    );
}
```

Comment: The second `useEffect` watches changes in `props.data`. What I'm not sure about: Does this mean it has to compare the current `props.data` with the previous `props.data` all the time? Which would be very expensive...

Comment: @Michael yes, react will make a strict equal comparison ‘===‘ under the hood and run the code if it is not equal anymore. If you want to be able to control the data prop from outside when rendering the component wrapper, it has to be like this, unless you work with some sort of events. What the best approach is, really depends on when you original heavy component needs the fresh data. For instance if it only needs the data once, you can limit the updateData to only run exactly once after the first render.